# Using gcc 4.8 or newer with RedHawk

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running RedHawk 1.10 on CentOS6.5 which uses gcc 4.4.7, but I am interested in a more recent version of gcc such as 4.8 or 4.9.  I know that newer versions can be installed.  Has anyone had experience using these with RedHawk?  Are there any problems?

Comment: Or has anyone run RedHawk on CentOS7 which I believe uses gcc 4.8.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Redhawk has had some mild testing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which I think has gcc 4.8.2 as its default.

Should you run into any compilation issues, you should open tickets on the github page.